# Android: layout_wilih attribute error

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm on the Android tutorial and I keep getting this error message even though the  **layout_width** attribute is already supplied:

```
 "Binary XML file line #2: You must supply a layout_width attribute"
```

Please help! Thanks

Comment: show your xml file for the layout

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're supposed to declare android:layout_width, not layout_wilih